# How to create excel/csv report from Cassandra databse

Tags: cassandra, report, cassandra-3.0

I have to create a report from the data present in Cassandra DB. I am more in to RDBMS and pretty much new in to Cassandra DB. In RDBMS that task is quite easy, you can create complex queries with joins and create the report. But how we can acheieve the same thing in Cassandra DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bulk Loader (DSBulk) tool to export data from a Cassandra table.

However, it's not BI tool and there are no joins in Cassandra so you can't do complex queries. Once you've exported a table to a CSV file, you can manipulate it whichever way you want.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [Introduction to DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/introducing-datastax-bulk-loader)
- Blog - [DSBulk Unloading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading)
- Docs - [More data export examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkUnload.html)

DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick...My data is available in multiple tables and I need near real time data from those tables for my reporting. Don't we have some programming kind of solution. Cassandra is being used by so many people now, but I am surprised that I am not getting any solution for this simple scernario (atleast in case of RDBMS) over the internet.

Comment: @user2974954 due to its distributed design, Cassandra just isn't a good choice for OLAP/BI reporting use cases.  Much of what those reports require involves scanning an entire table, which for Cassandra is an anti-pattern.  Spark solves some of this, in that the data is pulled into RAM allowing for more complex queries.  But Spark isn't going to be fast.  In short, this works with RDBMSs because the underlying architecture is much different from Cassandra.

Comment: Can we quickly extract the data from required tables (for reporting) and then create the report through some python program. Anyone tried this before?